# HIVE Editor on HUE - Hadoop

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hue

I'm having some trouble with a simple code on HIVE Editor from HUE.

I need to run the following code:

```
ADD JAR '/user/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar';
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE teste (
  `id` STRING,
  `created_time` STRING,
  `message` STRING,
  `likes_count` BIGINT,
  `comments_count` BIGINT,
  `shares_count` BIGINT,
  `people_reached_count` BIGINT,
  `poll_time` STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/admin/facebook/pageposts';
```

But it gives this message

"Error while processing statement: '/user/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar' does not exist."

And as you can see bellow, there is no problem with the path I'm using.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I think, jar location should be your local directory not HDFS. Can you try putting it in local hive lib directory. Also HUE UI provides upload UDF functionality. You can try using that also.This link can be useful for hive UDF- http://nexr.github.io/hive-udf/

Comment: Did you add the jar as a resource in the 'Settings' tab? e.g. http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-hive-udf-in-1-minute/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a jar from hdfs you must specify that its in hdfs and not the local file system.

```
ADD JAR hdfs:///user/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar ;
```